# How to render a record in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Demo.tsx` file, in which I am using `temp` that is a `Record` as shown below:

```
interface Info{ Name:string, id:string, } 
const [temp, setTemp] = useState<Record<string,Info>({ 
   "1": { 
          Name: "abc", 
          id: "1", 
    },
});
```

I want to iterate through this `Record` and print the value of `Name`.

This is my approach:

```
return ( { Object.keys( temp ).map(( el ) => { temp[ el ].Name })} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Rendering Multiple Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Example with js:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState({ "1": { name: "abc", id: "1" } });
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(temp).map(({ name, id }) => (
        <div key={id}>{name}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```